# Man pages offline for e-reader?

Tags: manpage

Is there anywhere one can get a copy of Ubuntu's man pages in e-reader (preferably Kindle/mobi, epub can be handled)format?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This bash command will dump HTML files for every man page on the system.  You'll need to install the `groff` package first, then `cd` to an empty directory and run:

```
for f in `ls -1 /usr/share/man/man*`; do n=`echo $f | sed s/[.].*[.]gz//`; man -Thtml $n > $n.html ; done
```

This will cycle through all of the files in the `/usr/share/man` directory, strip off the section number and the extension using `sed`, then call `man` to render the manpage to HTML (`man -Thtml` in turn calls `groff`, which is why you need it installed first), storing the result in an html file with the same name as the page.  It will take a while to complete, and `groff` throws some warnings about line breaks, but when it finishes, you will have all of your man pages in HTML format.

Most e-readers can handle HTML files, but if yours doesn't, you can use calibre to convert the HTML files to mobi or epub or any other format you choose.

Comment: You can try also `man -Tdvi` and `dvi2pdf` after that to get a bunch of PDFs.

Comment: Sounds excellent.  I knew there was a way to get PDF output, but PDFs don't reflow well

Comment: I've had pretty good luck using Calibre to convert pdf's for my kindle and android.   (Text and html convert well, of course.)

Answer (score 1):

all man pages are located at

```
/usr/share/man
```

But they're compressed in .gz files.
Also there's a [web](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online_pages.html) where you can see all man pages online.
I guess if you search a software who gives you the possibility to download all content of each page/link, you can create your own man-pages library for e reader

Comment: The mentioned downloading software could be `wget -R`.

Answer (score 1):

You can ask to man to convert a manpage into HTML and then [running a command to display it](https://askubuntu.com/a/339268/288303). So you can import a man page directly into *calibre* with (If you obtain something like `command exited with status 3`, install `groff` package):

```
man --html=calibre YOUR_MANPAGE
```

You can also import you manpage to calibre database without running GUI:

```
man --html='calibredb add' YOUR_MANPAGE
```

Once your manpage is in calibre, you can easily send them to your e-reader (I suggest to send them as *.mobi* format).

Now, just iterate over the list of manpage you want to import:

```
find /usr/share/man/man[1-9] -type f | xargs -l man --html='calibredb add'
```