# How do I make man pages open in a web browser?

Tags: browser, manpage

How can I make manpages (from the `man` command) open in a web browser for easier navigation?

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/ -- that way you have most everything you can dream of. There are scripts to transform manuals into HTML, but unless you transform them all, links won't work as expected. Also readability is exceptional in a console too. Maybe you meant better navigation?

Comment: @kevin I'd rather use a web browser (I'm more familiar with it) and I found that `gman` would become unresponsive after opening a page

Comment: understood. gman can use a browser, but I see your point. plus it does lack navigation ability.I had just posted that as you added to your question. ;-) you could also take a look at the dwww package.

Comment: This may not be your solution, but in knoqueror, you could type man:<your command>> to access the man pages in a browser. This will require you to install the kde libs.

Comment: There's another alternative to http://linux.die.net to view man pages preprocessed and beautified online: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/index.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### man2html

#### To search man pages

I installed the `man2html` package then navigated to `http://localhost/cgi-bin/man/man2html` to view the man pages. These pages can be viewed offline, link to other man pages and feature a search function.
 [Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20150317121959/http://linuxers.org/article/make-manpages-navigable-using-man2html)

#### To directly open a page (from command line)

I made this script [here](http://mysticpaste.com/view/5GXoo0rnE4?12) (it's not short), it just navigates directly to the webpage (from `man2html`) for a certain manpage. It can open multiple man pages specified as command line arguments. Save the script somewhere and give it execute permissions (`chmod +x script.sh`). Run it as `~/script.sh` (assuming saved in `~` directory) with pages to open as arguments. To open something like `init(8)`, use `~/script "8 init"`.

---

### dwww

#### To search man pages

Install the `dwww` paackage and navigate to `http://localhost/dwww/man/1` to search the pages. These pages can be viewed offline, link to other man pages and feature a search function.

#### To directly open a page (from command line)

I made this script [here](http://mysticpaste.com/view/Pq2R4xWxB7/text) (it's not short), it just navigates directly to the webpage (from `dwww`) for a certain manpage. It can open multiple man pages specified as command line arguments. Save the script somewhere and give it execute permissions (`chmod +x script.sh`). Run it as `~/script.sh page` (assuming saved in `~` directory) with pages to open as arguments. To open something like `init(8)`, use `~/script init/8`. Without `pcregrep`, you need to type the `/8` all the time, with it, just type the name of the page.

Answer (score 60):

### Using the man program

Looking at the manpage of man,

```
man man
```

There is the `-H` option, or its equivalent `--html` which will generate the HTML for the manual and open them in the browser.

> This  option  will  cause  groff  to produce HTML output, and will display that output in a web browser.  The choice of browser is determined by the optional browser argument if one is provided, by the $BROWSER environment variable, or by a compile-time default if that is unset (usually lynx).  This option implies -t, and will only work with GNU troff.

So to open any man page in the browser just use:

```
man -Hfirefox <command>
```

or

```
man --html=firefox <command>
```

Both are the same.

You can use `firefox`, `google-chrome`, `chromium-browser` or any other in place of the `firefox` word.

#### Select a default browser permanently

Before calling the `man` command, use the following command:

```
export BROWSER=firefox
```

This way, you can just use `man -H` or `man --html` without specifying the browser each time.

```
man -H ls
```

You can also add the previous `export` command to your `~/.bashrc` so you won't have to type it each time you open a new terminal and try using `man -H`

#### Troubleshoot

If you got an error saying something like this:

```
man: command exited with status 3: /usr/bin/zsoelim | /usr/lib/man-db/manconv -f UTF-8:ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8//IGNORE | preconv -e UTF-8 | tbl | groff -mandoc -Thtml
```

You will need to install the `groff` package.

```
sudo apt-get install groff
```

---

### Using Yelp

If a choice of browser is not relevant, you can use the `yelp` command which offers navigation through the man pages.

```
yelp man:<command>
# example: yelp man:ls
```

---

### Using the Ubuntu Manpage Repository

You can also visit https://manpages.ubuntu.com/ and check almost all man pages there. All versions of the man pages for all the Ubuntu versions are available there. It also features a search functionality.

Of course, the downside of using the website is that you can't access it without being connected to the Internet.

Comment: You can use the command xdg-open which would open the systems defalt too

Comment: and you would need groff installed

Comment: @user1281385 I was going to mention it, but it has a few issues. For example, my default is Firefox. If I try to use it, and I already have Firefox open, it shows me the error which says `Firefox is already running, but is not responding. To open a new window, you must first close the existing Firefox process, or restart your system.` I did mention installing `groff`

Comment: manpages.ubuntu.com seems useful!

Comment: +1 Thanks! I had written a whole script to do this awhile ago. This is *much* easier!

Comment: It is worth noting that `man -H` also works when `man` is an alias for [`pinfo`](http://pinfo.sourceforge.net), like `alias man='pinfo -m'`, except for `pinfo` opening an empty page which can be closed immediately. Excellent protip!

Comment: -Hfirefox doesn't work on 18.04: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Error: cannot open display: :0

Comment: I'm getting "File not found // Firefox can’t find the file at /tmp/hmanOZ02pL/man.html." Probably because launching new instance of firefox like that passes control to existing instance and immediately exits, which is why temporary file gets deleted even before "real" firefox gets a chance to open it.

Comment: `man --html=google-chrome man
Failed to move to new namespace: PID namespaces supported, Network namespace supported, but failed: errno = Operation not permitted
Trace/breakpoint trap
man: couldn't execute any browser from google-chrome`

Comment: `#!/bin/bash    
firefox "https://manpages.ubuntu.com/cgi-bin/search.py?q=$1"`

Answer (score 18):

`man` can actually do a lot of this on its own. You just need to install [`groff`](https://www.gnu.org/software/groff/) (GNU troff text-formatting system) and then you can use [the `H` flag](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/man.1.html#options) (cause `groff` to produce HTML output).

```
sudo apt install groff
man -Hfirefox bash
```

Answer (score 2):

In response to [Dan](https://askubuntu.com/a/339268/1138297) and [ratijas comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/339255/how-do-i-make-man-pages-open-in-a-web-browser/339268#comment2174882_339268) : you can force firefox to open in a new process

```bsh
man -H"firefox -new-instance -P 'default'" ls
```

I personnally have aliased it as `man` :

```sh
alias man="man -H'firefox -new-instance -P default'"
```

Comment: Interesting.  Unfortunately I get a cryptic error message `"man: command exited with status 3: (cd /tmp/hmanNNO85n && /usr/lib/man-db/zsoelim) | (cd /tmp/hmanNNO85n && /usr/lib/man-db/manconv -f UTF-8:ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8//IGNORE) | (cd /tmp/hmanNNO85n && preconv -e UTF-8) | (cd /tmp/hmanNNO85n && tbl) | (cd /tmp/hmanNNO85n && groff -mandoc -Thtml)`

Comment: The `/tmp/blahblah` directory is not created.  Adding `sudo` doesn't work either.

Comment: @CraigHicks The status 3 error can be fixed by installing groff