# How do I view the man pages?

Tags: command-line, documentation, manpage

I'm new to Linux. I got the "Unix And Linux System Administration Handbook" It speaks of several verisons of linux and unix, and the commands for viewing linux man pages and not specific to ubuntu.

How do I view the manpages?

Comment: You just said this book talks about the commands for vewing man pages...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get help on terminal commands?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/991946/how-can-i-get-help-on-terminal-commands)

Answer (score 29):

To view a manual page related to a package, open a terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> together) and type:

```
man <package_name>
```

For example, to view `grep`'s manual page, type:

```
man grep
```

This will open the manual page referring to the section numbers in the order:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

If you want to open the manual page of a specific section, type:

```
man <section_number> <package_name>
```

For example, to open the manual page of the `open()` function in C, you should type:

```
man 2 open
```

More information:

- Refer to the [the manual page for `man`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/man).
- Search through Ubuntu Manpages at: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/.

Comment: Also, some tools have more extensive manuals in info pages (so `info grep`); and some commands that are an internal part of the bash shell rather than being separate external files are documented on help pages (for example: `help echo`). And, of course, many programs have a `--help` option that displays the most common usages.

Comment: @evilsoup: Feel free to add it to the answer.

Comment: To open the manual page of all sections, type `man -a <page>`. And note that the argument doesn't have to be a package name. It can be a command, a file, a function name, ...

Comment: Sorry, but this is IMO too inacurrate.  The `man` argument is **manpage name, not package name**.  `grep` is not a package (neither is `open` or `ascii` or `hier`), but a command that is part of `coreutils` package. `man coreutils` does not give anything since that page does not exist. The convention (followed by most, but not all packages) is to add a manpage per command, which is why `man grep` works, but there are manpages that don't describe commands. `man` does not really have concept of packages (aside from minor meta info displayed in footer).

Answer (score 7):

**@Jobin** answer is perfect, I always like to add more options so Op can know it.

If you want to redirect a command man to a txt file:

```
man <command> > /location/file (change location and the name of file )
```

Another thing I would like you to know:

When for example you type `man ls`, you will see LS (1) at the top, numbers mean:

```
 (1)     User Commands
 (2)     System Calls
 (3)     Library functions
 (4)     Devices
 (5)     File formats
 (6)     Games and Amusements
 (7)     Conventions and Miscellany
 (8)     System Administration and Priveledged Commands
 (L)     Local. Some programs install their man pages into this section instead 
 (N)     TCL commands
```

And if you want to view man pages on terminal I would prefer to use:

`man <command> | less` so you can view it as pages

For more options: `man man`

Comment: Why would one need to pipe man to `less` if it already uses a pager, which by default is (at least on my system) `/usr/bin/less -s` and can be specified by `-P` option or `$PAGER` env var?

Answer (score 2):

If using unity you can also access thru the Dash via yelp & the manpages scope

Open Dash home, type in `manpages:whatever`, ex. `manpages:bash`

Available man's will be displayed, when clicked on open in help window

The bookmark option in help when opened this way is semi useful, could be better.

Answer (score 2):

You can also [view man pages in a browser](https://askubuntu.com/questions/339255/how-do-i-make-man-pages-open-in-a-web-browser).

Install the `man2html` package using `sudo apt-get install man2html` and then navigate to `http://localhost/cgi-bin/man/man2html`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `man package/command(name)` and for more information about how `man` works try using `man man`

Answer (score 1):

Your knee-jerk reaction when trying to study about new *command* or *config file* should be:

```
man command
man file.conf
```

or

```
man command<Tab>
man file<Tab>
```

The argument to `man` is actually *manpage name* and the package maintainer is expected to add any manpages users would need.  For many prolific packages, you can normally expect:

- one manpage per command -- named exactly as the command,
- at least one manpage about configuration files (typically named exactly
  as the main configuration file).

However the man page system is a huge, really rich resource.  There are actually far more man pages that don't deal with particular command or even particular program.  For example, the manpage system typically contains documentation of:

- commands (section 1) but often also pages that are not directly commands
  eg. perlre,
- kernel calls (section 2),
- system library calls (section 3),
- special system files (section 4),
- configuration files and formats (section 5),
- games (yes, games! .. although I've never seen anything there) (section 6),
- miscellaneous stuff (like `man 7 ascii`, `man 7 iso-8859-1`,
  `man 7 wireless`) (section 7)

Also, packages may provide their documentation as manpage sections.  For example, `perl-doc` adds section `3perl` where you can find all its modules, OpenSSL adds `3ssl`.

Not sure if it's on Ububtu, but on Fedora there is `man-pages` package that provides even more goods like POSIX versions of commands or system calls.

Answer (score 0):

Just my 2¢:
If you type `man man` (i.e. looking up the manpage for man) you get:

```
* man (1) 
man (7mp) 
man (1p) 
Man: What manual page do you want? 
Man:
```

This shows you what sections are available for a given man page.  You can type in 1, 7mp, 1p to view whichever fits your fancy. 1p, for example, is the manpage for the command as defined by POSIX.  If you are feeling particularly lazy, you can just hit enter at the `Man:` prompt and it will go to the default (*) section.

You can tell man which section you want by adding the section number to your request like (looking for info on `mkdir` command):
`man 1 mkdir`
or
`man mkdir.1`
or
`man mkdir(1)`

As far as the sections, I might suggest the following guide (from man 2.10.2):

The table below shows the section numbers of the manual followed by  the  types  of
pages they contain.

| section | content |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Header files (usually found in /usr/include) |
| 1 | Executable programs or shell commands |
| 2 | System calls (functions provided by the kernel) |
| 3 | Library calls (functions within program libraries) |
| 4 | Special files (usually found in /dev) |
| 5 | File formats and conventions, e.g. /etc/passwd |
| 6 | Games |
| 7 | Miscellaneous (including macro packages and conventions), e.g. man(7), groff(7), man-pages(7) |
| 8 | System administration commands (usually only for root) |
| 9 | Kernel routines [Non standard] |

If you get bored w/ output you can change the pager to something like `bat` or use a colorizer.  There are several ways to do this, just search for "how to colorize man page output" or something like that.  It is worth looking over the manpage on `man` and on `less` (the default pager used by `man`) as it will make looking up stuff a lot easier in the future.  It is good to know that you can do something even if you have to look up how some other time.